# Optimization problem, code runs but no output

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, gurobi

In this optimization problem, my code runs but without giving any output nor error messages and all packages have been correctly installed. I couldn't spot any syntax errors, who has an idea about how to make it work?

```
def opti():
    M=7
    K=5
    z_K=[]

    for m in range (M):
        d1= np.random.uniform(50,250,K)
        d2= np.random.uniform(20,250,K)
        d3= np.random.uniform(200,500,K)
        m=gp.Model("opti")
        x_1= m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="The resources R1 that should be procured")
        x_2= m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="The resources R2 that should be procured")
        x_3= m.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="The resources R3 that should be procured")
        y_1= m.addVar([k for i in range (K)], vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="The amount of P1 producted")
        y_2= m.addVar([k for i in range (K)], vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="The amount of P2 producted")
        y_3= m.addVar([k for i in range (K)], vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="The amount of P3 producted")

        m.setObjective(2*x_1+4*x_2+5.2*X_3+(1/K)*sum(-17.6*y_1[i]-12.2*y_2[i]+0.6*y_3[i]
                        for i in range (K)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
        m.addConstr(x_1>=0)
        m.addConstr(x_2>=0)
        m.addConstr(x_3>=0)
        m.addConstr(y_1>=0)
        m.addConstr(y_2>=0)
        m.addConstr(y_3>=0)

        for k in range (K):
            m.addConstr(y_1[k]==d1[k])
            m.addConstr(y_2[k]==d2[k])
            m.addConstr(y_3[k]==d3[k])

            m.optimize()
            z_K.append(m.getObjective().getValue())

            L_MK= sum(z_K)/M

            #std
            sigma=(1/(M-1)*sum((z_K[k]-L_MK)**2 for k in range (M)))**(0.5)
            #CI 95%
            ci=[L_MK-sigma*1.29/(M**(0.5)),L_MK+sigma*1.29/(M**(0.5))]

            print ('z_K', z_K)
            print ('L_MK', L_MK)
            print ('standard deviation', sigma)
            print ('confidence interval', ic)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation and add relevant imports to ensure that your code is runnable

Comment: your function just defines 3 variables and then does nothing. Those variables will be immediately destroyed by the garbage collector.

Comment: check your variable names, you already did `for m in range (M):
`, then later overwrite `m` with `m=gp.Model("opti")`

Comment: it worked after some indentation fixing and omitting the def function. Thank you